# recall array in Form load event

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with a textbox. If I type in "91" it should give me grade A and so forth. If I put my array in my button click it works. However, if I put it in my form load event, it only works once. Do I have to recall it everytime?

```
Public Class Form1
Structure Grades
    Public intMinGrade As Integer
    Public strLetterGrade As String
End Structure
Dim graGradingScale(5) As Grades
Dim index As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    'For i As Integer = 0 To graGradingScale.Length - 1
    '    MessageBox.Show(graGradingScale(i).intMinGrade)
    'Next

    Dim FoundBoolean As Boolean = False
    Do Until FoundBoolean Or index > 5

        If TextBox1.Text = graGradingScale(index).intMinGrade.ToString Then

            Label1.Text = graGradingScale(index).strLetterGrade.ToString
            FoundBoolean = True
        Else
            index += 1

        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    graGradingScale(0).intMinGrade = 91
    graGradingScale(0).strLetterGrade = "A"
    graGradingScale(1).intMinGrade = 81
    graGradingScale(1).strLetterGrade = "B"
    graGradingScale(2).intMinGrade = 71
    graGradingScale(2).strLetterGrade = "C"
    graGradingScale(3).intMinGrade = 61
    graGradingScale(3).strLetterGrade = "D"
    graGradingScale(4).intMinGrade = 0
    graGradingScale(4).strLetterGrade = "F"

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the `Dim index As Integer` inside the `Button1_Click`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    'code continues
```

valter